# How do I copy all tables in database to Excel

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and I wanted to quickly copy all the data in the database into either separate Excel spreadsheets or into a single spreadsheet in separate tabs.  Putting the data into separate CSV files is also ok.  How do I do this without having to do a `select * from` for each of the tables and then copying the data into Excel?  There are a lot of tables.

**EDIT**

Running the wizard to export data I get this error on Pre-execute

- Pre-execute (Error)

  Messages
  Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

  Error 0xc0202025: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

  Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: component "Destination - ApprovalStatuses" (25) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Have you considered the Export Data option within Enterprise Manager? You can specify Excel as the destination

Comment: Does this support the copying of the entire database or do you have to copy table by table?

Comment: Table by table but can choose all the tables in a database and perform transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Server Management Studio:

```
Server Management Studio (right click on db) > 
  Tasks > 
      Export > 
         Login > 
            Destination box select Microsoft Excel > ...
```

If you are on a `64-bit server` then;

```
Windows > Start Button > 
     All Programs >
         MS Sql Server [your version] > 
             USE Import and Export Data (32-bit)
```

Comment: I get the error "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered."

Comment: To register that provider you have to install the Access Database Engine components on your server - [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: Or perhaps try this: `Windows` > `Start > MS Sql Server [your version]` > USE `Import and Export Data (32-bit)`

Comment: I have now installed the Access Database Engine and ran the export but get all sorts of other errors now.

Comment: You think should be able to select what you want. Play around a bit you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

See this link http://www.66pacific.com/sql_server_export_to_excel.aspx

Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, you can easily copy tables from the database to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I alraedy saw this but it said that you had to prepare a Excel spreadsheet beforehand by creating the headers in the spreadsheet manually.

Comment: Ok, Import and Export Wizards using this method is the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can directrly export table from database to `excel` file using `sql-server Import and Export Wizard`.

Have look at this article about [Exporting SQL Server Data to Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952922%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, see this link http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/windows-net-programming/59962-export-data-database-excel-via-sql-command-customize-style-vb-net-without-auto.html for a quick way of doing it.

Ideally, if you get time to program it, I would use RDLC to build custom reports which you can export out as Excel using DataTables.

See my blog post at https://mashupweb.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/creating-an-online-list-of-users-in-a-database-using-report-wizard/ on how export data onto Excel using RDLC.

Comment: If you are using RDLC, you can use SQLCommand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx for obtaining the data from MS SQL